# Naming file in batch script to test.yyyy.mm.dd.hh.mm.ss

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to format the date and time in using batch scripting so that my file corresponds to current date time.

if current date time is:2015.09.02.13:21:22

I would like the file to be called: `TEST.2015.09.02.13:21:22`

Is this doable?

Comment: chech this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

```
echo TEST.%date:~-4%.%date:~4,2%.%date:~7,2%.%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%.%time:~6,2%
```

and it should give:

```
TEST.2015.02.09.14.00.35
```